# Fill In for Null Values for Date, Product Code & QTY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am more than likely not using the correct search string to attempt to find an relevant thread on here so my apologies if it is. I am trying to write out a code for our products that calculates total in-use per calendar day but I am getting results where if there is none in-use then the date record (Date/Product Code/Qty In-Use) falls off. In my attempts I have been able to fill in for dates & 0 in-use but my Product Code is null and it's there where I am stuck (Null Records image below).

I need to fill in the missing records with the product code.

Null Records:

[image: Null Records]

My probably-not-ideal bit of code for this latest attempt for testing is below. The declared variables are just for this specific instance while I trial-and-error this out:

```
    DECLARE @STARTDT DATE
    DECLARE @ENDDT DATE
    DECLARE @ECODE VARCHAR (100)
    DECLARE @SORDER VARCHAR (100)

    SET @STARTDT = '2020-02-01'
    SET @ENDDT = '2020-02-29'
    SET @ECODE = 'P2364-'

    ;

    WITH STEP0 AS 

        (

            SELECT
                DD0.DATE

            FROM Dim_Date DD0

        ),

    STEP1 AS

        (

            SELECT  
                DE.ECODE AS 'ECODE',
                CASE
                    WHEN DE.SOURCE = 'REV' THEN DE.ECODE
                    ELSE DE.MCODE 
                END AS 'MCODE',
                DD.DATE 'DATE',
                ISNULL(SUM(RRD.INUSE),0)  'INUSE'

        FROM Dim_Date AS DD
            LEFT OUTER JOIN wFACT_ECODES_RentalRowsDAILY_ECODE_NOSEC2 AS RRD ON DD.DATE = RRD.DATE
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN DIM_ECODES DE ON RRD.ECODE = DE.ECODE

            WHERE
                DD.DATE BETWEEN @STARTDT AND @ENDDT AND
                DE.MCODE = @ECODE

            GROUP BY 
                DE.ECODE,
                CASE
                    WHEN DE.SOURCE = 'REV' THEN DE.ECODE
                    ELSE DE.MCODE 
                END,
                DD.DATE

        )

    SELECT 
        S0.DATE,
        ISNULL(S1.MCODE,S1.MCODE),
        ISNULL(S1.INUSE,0)

    FROM STEP0 S0
        LEFT OUTER JOIN STEP1 S1 ON S0.Date = S1.DATE

    WHERE
        S0.Date BETWEEN @STARTDT AND @ENDDT

    ORDER BY 
        S0.Date
```

Let me know if additional information is needed or I need to be more clear on something. Thank you for your expert help and I'll do my best to further explain or answer as requested.

**wFACT_ECODES_RentalRowsDAILY_ECODE_NOSEC2** table sample data :

| ECODE | MCODE | DATE | INUSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/23/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/25/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/26/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/27/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/28/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/29/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/30/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 1/31/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/1/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/2/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/3/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/5/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/6/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/7/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/8/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/9/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/10/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/11/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/12/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/13/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/14/2020 | 1 |

**DIM_ECODES table sample data**

| ECODE | MCODE | CCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | P2368-40 |
| P2364- | P2364- | P2364- |

**DIM_DATE** table sample data

| DATE |
| --- |
| 2020-02-01 |
| 2020-02-02 |
| 2020-02-03 |
| 2020-02-04 |
| 2020-02-05 |
| 2020-02-06 |
| 2020-02-07 |
| 2020-02-08 |
| 2020-02-09 |
| 2020-02-10 |
| 2020-02-11 |
| 2020-02-12 |
| 2020-02-13 |
| 2020-02-14 |
| 2020-02-15 |
| 2020-02-16 |
| 2020-02-17 |
| 2020-02-18 |
| 2020-02-19 |
| 2020-02-20 |
| 2020-02-21 |
| 2020-02-22 |
| 2020-02-23 |
| 2020-02-24 |
| 2020-02-25 |
| 2020-02-26 |
| 2020-02-27 |
| 2020-02-28 |
| 2020-02-29 |

***Expected/Desired Results***

| ECODE | MCODE | DATE | INUSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/1/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/2/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/3/2020 | 1 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/4/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/5/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/6/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/7/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/8/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/9/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/10/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/11/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/12/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/13/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/14/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/15/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/16/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/17/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/18/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/19/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/20/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/21/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/22/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/23/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/24/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/25/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/26/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/27/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/28/2020 | 0 |
| P2368-40 | P2364- | 2/29/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/1/2020 0 |  |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/2/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/3/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/4/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/5/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/6/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/7/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/8/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/9/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/10/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/11/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/12/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/13/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/14/2020 | 1 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/15/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/16/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/17/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/18/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/19/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/20/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/21/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/22/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/23/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/24/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/25/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/26/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/27/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/28/2020 | 0 |
| P2364- | P2364- | 2/29/2020 | 0 |

Comment: Sample data and desired results as *text tables* would be a big help!

Comment: That code for creating a text table is very foreign to me, I can't add an excel file with two tabs?

Comment: . . Your query refers to multiple tables.  I expect to see sample data for each one.  Perhaps they are not all necessary and you can simplify the query and the data in the question.

Comment: Hope I did that right, doesn't quite look like others' format.

Comment: Looks good actually.

Comment: Shat, forgot expected...stand by

Comment: I should had mentioned that our product code table is actually over 150k, just to be sure we're not defining the fill in for the product code to a static P2364-.

Comment: No joy, @GordonLinoff?